# Laravel Route:list not working throwing run time exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when i tried to display all routes

by using `php artisan route:list`

it showing some runtime exception like this

```
  [RuntimeException]
  Session store not set on request.
```

how can i get my list of routes

Comment: open the file routes/web.php

Comment: That artisan command can often fail if there are exceptions thrown elsewhere in your application, for example, if an exception is thrown during construction of any of your controllers, then the command will fail